Get user role in OSB pipeline
In OSB 12C, I have a proxy service that has basic authentication enabled. The 3rd party calling it has to supply a user/password defined from the WebLogic console in the security realm. Data is returned in JSON.
There is a requirement that certain class of users / callers be returned basic information while another class be shown additional privileged info. As an example, when regular partners call: http://server:7003/Parts/getPart?id=1 should return:
{
  "id": 1,
  "listing": "Hub caps",
  "price": 1000
}

And when a premium partner calls the same service, the return should be:
{
  "id": 1,
  "listing": "Hub caps",
  "price": 1000,
  "bulkqty": 10,
  "bulkprice": 900
}

Since the basic header is not passed on to the business service, it always returns all elements. What I was planning to do, was to put the users into separate groups/roles and transform the response received from the business service within the pipeline so that the proxy response has the last 2 elements only when the user id belongs to the PremiumPartners group.
I don't see any isUserInGroup or similar function. Any ideas?
